# @synchronized (self) - best way

Tags: ios, synchronization, synchronized

I've currently started to work on how @synchronized works, and how it can lock objects.

```
@synchronized(self) {
    [self getDataWithCompletionBlock:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [refreshControl endRefreshing];
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            loadingView.hidden = YES;
            self.oneTimeCallReach = NO;
        });
    }];
}
```

Is this completely wrong?

Comment: Probably? It's hard to say if something is wrong without knowing what you are trying to do.  That will only lock until the `getDataWithCompletionBlock` call returns, not lock until your asynchronous call comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are updating some model objects asynchronously inside `getDataWithCompletionBlock`. Unfortunately, the code you posted will not synchronize asynchronous updates. Neither those updates, nor your completion block, itself, will be synchronized with that code.

Assuming you want to synchronize data that is asynchronously retrieved, you should:

- remove the synchronized directive wrapping your method call;
- don't update model objects inside the method;
- instead, just retrieve it to a local variable which you then pass back in an additional parameter to the completion block;
- then, in your completion block, perform the model update using the parameter passed to the block, synchronizing it as needed.

By the way, if you dispatch the updating of the model to the main queue, you may be able to retire `synchronized` directive entirely and instead use the main thread to synchronize all updates. (Dispatching updates and access to a serial queue is perfectly acceptable way to synchronize access from multiple threads, and main queue is, itself, a serial queue.) If all read and writes to the model take place on the main thread, that achieves the necessary synchronization. Obviously, though, if you're accessing the model from other threads, then you will need to synchronize it. But often restricting access to the model to the main thread is a nice, simple synchronization mechanism. As Apple says in their [*Concurrency Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW7):

> **Avoid Synchronization Altogether**
>
> For any new projects you work on, and even for existing projects, designing your code and data structures to avoid the need for synchronization is the best possible solution. Although locks and other synchronization tools are useful, they do impact the performance of any application. And if the overall design causes high contention among specific resources, your threads could be waiting even longer.
>
> The best way to implement concurrency is to reduce the interactions and inter-dependencies between your concurrent tasks. If each task operates on its own private data set, it does not need to protect that data using locks. Even in situations where two tasks do share a common data set, you can look at ways of partitioning that set or providing each task with its own copy. Of course, copying data sets has its costs too, so you have to weigh those costs against the costs of synchronization before making your decision.

Anyway, if you wanted to minimize he need to synchronize yourself, it might look like:

```
[self getDataWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *results){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.objects = results;
        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        loadingView.hidden = YES;
        self.oneTimeCallReach = NO;
    });
}];
```

Now, clearly, I don't know what your model is, so my `NSArray` example is probably not right, but hopefully this illustrates the idea. Let the completion handler take care of synchronized updates (and if you don't have any other threads accessing the model directly, then use main queue to synchronize access).

Personally, I might also include some error parameter so that the block that updates the UI can detect and handle any errors that might occur.